# Список всевозможных комбинаций чисел из 7 цифр от 0 до 9 без возможности повтора

Tags: математика, bat, комбинаторика, числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Правильно ли написан .bat? Проверьте, пожалуйста.
Требуется список всевозможных комбинаций чисел из 7 цифр от 0 до 9 без возможности повтора.

В блокнот скопируем семь строк

```
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,9) DO echo 000%%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (10,1,99) DO echo 00%%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (100,1,999) DO echo 0%%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (1000,1,9999) DO echo %%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (10000,1,99999) DO echo %%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (100000,1,999999) DO echo %%i>> stat.txt
FOR /L %%i IN (1000000,1,9999999) DO echo %%i>> stat.txt
```

Сохрани как run.bat и затем - кликни по нему (запуск с правами админа).

Через время - файл с комбинациями будет лежать в той же папке или %system32%

Comment: Запустите и посмотрите, в чем вопрос?... Только вот первое же число - 0000. Цифр не 7, сплошной повтор нулей...

Comment: @Harry, не разбираетесь не пишите!

Comment: Так не в чем разбираться - вопрос-то вы корректно не сформулировали. Возвращаю: "Не умеете спрашивать - не пишите" :) Не думаю, что кто-то вообще озаботится вам ответить...

Comment: @Harry, тогда поправьте, и напишите пример на основе моего кода....

Comment: Я написал свой ответ. На основе вашего кода у меня ничего не получится (вернее, получится, но это будет длинно и некрасиво...)

Comment: @Harry, ну и пускай ) как есть напишите ) подсмотрю Вашу идею

Comment: `for %i in (6,1,9) do echo 012345%i` - ну, и так далее :) Ну не годится ваша идея. Это как закручивать шурупы гаечным ключом...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо! :) Эксперементирую

Answer (score 2):

Ну, раз Stanislav Volodarskiy дал ответ по поводу размещений, я скажу о сочетаниях :)

Вот файл, который выводит все 120 **сочетаний** из 7 цифр из 10 возможных:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /L %%g in (6,1,9) do (
  set x=%%g
  set /A x=x-1
  for /L %%f in (5,1,!x!) do (
    set y=%%f
    set /A y=y-1
    for /L %%e in (4,1,!y!) do (
      set z=%%e
      set /A z=z-1
      for /L %%d in (3,1,!z!) do (
        set u=%%d
        set /A u=u-1
        for /L %%c in (2,1,!u!) do (
          set v=%%c
          set /A v=v-1
          for /L %%b in (1,1,!v!) do (
            set w=%%b
            set /A w=w-1
            for /L %%a in (0,1,!w!) do echo %%a%%b%%c%%d%%e%%f%%g
          )    
        )    
      )    
    )      
  )
)
                
endlocal
```

А уж куда перенаправить его вывод - дело десятое :)

Если немного повозиться - можно написать и размещение...

Answer (score 0):

.bat составлен неправильно. Он порождает `10 + 90 + 900 + 9000 + 90000 + 900000 + 9000000 = 10000000` комбинаций.

Речь о числе размещений [A(n, k)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Количество способов выбрать всевозможные размещения 7 из 10 цифр без повторов равно `A(10, 7)  = 10! / (10 - 7)! = 604800`.

Числа не совпадают, следовательно .bat составлен неправильно.

Comment: Терминологический вопрос: "комбинации" - это сочетания или размещения? Далее, я указал в комментарии, что первое же число идет с повторениями цифр - на что получил гневную отповедь *"не разбираетесь не пишите"*, так что по всей видимости, ваш ответ тоже окажется неверен с точки зрения автора (который старательно хранит тайну, что же именно ему нужно...)

Comment: @Harry, спасибо! В таком разговоре важно придерживаться терминологии.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, напишите правильный пример .bat. Мне очень интересно КАК. Дайте в виде ответа что-ли...